# "Made look better" vs. "made to look better"

Tags: grammaticality, sense-verbs, particles, causative-verbs

> - Results are made to look better by...
> - Results are made look better by...

Are both correct? Is there another way of phrasing this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting that the active transform

- *They made the results look better by ...*

does **not** allow the presence of *to*

- **They made the results **to** look better by ...*

whereas the passive

- *The results were made **to** look better by ...*

**requires** *to*

- **The results were made look better by ...*

Answer (score 1):

“**Made to look better**” is correct.

The second option is not grammatical.